# check if a node value is null

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have this xml file :

```
<key1>value 1</key1>
<key2>value 2</key2>
<key3>value 3</key3>
<key4>value 4</key4>
```

I would like to parse it and get a dictionnary containing all the attributes of my element.
To do that I have this code :

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    string key="";
    string value="";      
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                key=(reader.Name)
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                value=(reader.Value)
                element_dictionnary.Add(key,value);
                break;                
        }
    }    
}
```

Everything is working fine, the problem is if one node is empty like with this file :

```
<key1></key1>
<key2>value 2</key2>
<key3>value 3</key3>
<key4>value 4</key4>
```

Everything is shifted and my dictionnary becomes this :

key1/value2
key2/value3
.....

So basicaly, I would like to know how it's possible to associate the node value to the node name, even if the node value is empty.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The documentation says that you could check with `IsEmptyElement`, if the current element is empty: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have read this, the problem is that it's return true for self closing element like <tag/>, not for <tag></tag>

Answer (score 0):

Just check that reader.Value is empty using

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value)
```

So your code become

```
switch (reader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.Element:
        key=(reader.Name)
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.Text:
        value=(reader.Value)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            element_dictionnary.Add(key,value);
        break;                
}
```